# Dynamically update table view while typing/erasing in a textBox using ajax asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a @Html.textBox which is updating my view with a table (without refreshing the entire page), when a search-button is pressed. I am using Ajax to do this and it works fine.

My problem is that I want to dynamically update the table, without having to press the button.

For example, if I type "ordernumber 1" I want the table to dynamically update the table view with everything that starts with "ordernumber 1".

Should I use an If-statement somewhere that dynamically checks the textbox input or is there a better solution? :)

**My code:**

**Controller:**

```
 private LogDBContext db = new LogDBContext();

        // GET: LogModels

        //Adds parameters to search and order data from the database
        public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page, string sortOrder)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

            string myID = "0";
            if (Session["myID"] != null)
            {
                myID = Session["myID"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/");
            }
            int testID;
            try
            {
                testID = Convert.ToInt32(myID);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                throw new FormatException("FormatException error in LogModelsController", ex);
            }

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            //Linq code that gets data from the database
            var message = (from log in db.Log
                           where log.customerId == testID
                           select log);
            //message = message.Where(q => q.customerId.Equals(myID));

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                message = message.Where(s => s.message.Contains(searchString));
            }

            //PageSize displays the maximum number of rows on each page
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            return View(message.OrderByDescending(i => i.timeStamp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }



[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult LogPartialView(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page, string sortOrder)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

            string myID = "0";
            if (Session["myID"] != null)
            {
                myID = Session["myID"].ToString();
            }
            int testID;
            try
            {
                testID = Convert.ToInt32(myID);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                throw new FormatException("FormatException error in LogModelsController", ex);
            }

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
            //Linq code that gets data from the database
            var message = (from log in db.Log
                           where log.customerId == testID
                           select log);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                message = message.Where(s => s.message.Contains(searchString));
            }

            //PageSize displays the maximum number of rows on each page
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            return PartialView("_LogPartialLayout", message.OrderByDescending(i => i.timeStamp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
    }
```

**HTML-code: LogLayout**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogPartialView", "LogModelsController",
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    UpdateTargetId = "divLogs"
                                }, new
                                {
                                    id = "NewTableId"
                                }))
                                {
                                    <p>
                                        <b>Message:</b> @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                                        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />

                                    </p>
                                }<div id="divLogs">
                                    @RenderBody()
                                    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)

                                </div>
```

**HTML-code - PartialView:**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<namespace.Models.LogModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("message", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("timestamp", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("level", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.message)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeStamp)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.level)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```